Circuit breaker to use percentage of total calls made to the endpoint in half open state rather than using hard-coded value
In my implementation of circuit breaker, I need to use a percentage of total calls made to the endpoint in half open state (e.g 80% of total calls or 20% of total calls to be sent in half open state) rather than using hard-coded value.
I checked resilience4j, it does not provide the dynamic calculation during the half open state. I do not want to use any external service which can provide me the percentage value to be used in the circuit breaker configuration. How can this be achieved? Should I try creating my own implementation for circuit breaker following any library?
